# Read strings into 1 string from file while not Integer c++

Tags: c++, string

I have a file like this:

```
 Dr Joe Hugh 180
 Grand Johnson 180
```

And i want to read the name into a string but i dont know how long the name is:

```
string str;
```

Like this:

```
str = "Dr Joe Hugh"
or
str = "Grand Johnson"
```

And the number into:

```
int number;
```

**How am i supposed to indicate the program to read them while its not an integer?**

I thought about getline but i dont know how to do that

Comment: When is `str = "string1 string2 string3"` and when is `str = "string1 string2"`?

Comment: Will the number always be the last space-delimited part of the input string?

Comment: @leech it's like names,i want to read the whole name into 1 str,when i dont know how long the name is

Answer (score 1):

If the number is always at the end of the line and is always preceded by a space, you could do something like this:

```cpp
struct Line {
    std::string str;
    int number;
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Line &l) {
    if (std::getline(in, l.str)) {
        const char *last_space = l.str.c_str();

        for (const char &c : l.str)
            if (c == ' ')
                last_space = &c;

        l.number = std::atoi(last_space);
        l.str = l.str.substr(0, last_space - l.str.c_str());
    }

    return in;
}
```

Edit 2: Example usage:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::ifstream f("/path/to/file.txt");

    std::vector<Line> lines;

    // reads every line from the file into the vector
    for (Line l; f >> l; lines.push_back(std::move(l))) {}

    // do stuff with your vector of lines
}
```

Edit: At the expense of readability, an optimization to the above code (if the strings are very long) would be to replace the `for` loop that looks for the last space with one that loops through the string in reverse.

```cpp
for (auto it = l.str.crbegin(); it != l.str.crend(); ++it) {
    if (*it == ' ') {
        last_space = &*it;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If line always ends with an integer, you can create a much simpler solution using `while` loop with some conditions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool isNumber(std::string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(str[i]) && str[i] != '-') return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
   std::vector <std::string> names;
   std::vector <int> numbers;
   std::string str;
   int a;
   std::fstream file;
   file.open("PATH", std::ios::in);
   if (!file) return -1;
   while (file >> str)
   {
       if (isNumber(str))
       {
           a = stoi(str);
           numbers.push_back(a);
       }
       else names.push_back(str);
   }
}
```

Now you have a ready two vectors that contain numbers and names. If you want `names` to be lines, not just words, use `vector<vector<string>>` instead of `vector<string>`, and change the loop a bit to make it work :)